# Alipay Payment Gateway Error?

Tags: python, django, alipay

I am trying to integrate Alipay Gateway with my website using [this](https://github.com/liuyug/django-alipay). 
I am getting the payment form but on redirecting to Alipay's website I am getting the `ILLEGAL_PARTNER_EXTERFACE` (pic attached) error.
[image]

[Few responses](https://wordpress.org/plugins/alipay-for-woocommerce/faq/) for the error online say `payment type` is different for testing environment. Can anyone give any pointers how to solve this? Any other kit for Alipay integration with a `Django(python)` based website ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the official documentation [here](https://cshall.alipay.com/support/help_detail.htm?help_id=397107), the possible reasons for that error code are:

- You did not apply for this particular payment gateway type
- You did apply for this payment gateway type, but it has not been approved yet
- You did apply for this payment gateway type, but it has been suspended due to violation of ToS

In your case, I guess it should be the first one.

There are several gateway types:

- Alipay_Express (Alipay Express Checkout)
- Alipay_Secured (Alipay Secured Checkout)
- Alipay_Dual (Alipay Dual Function Checkout)
- ...

You need to make sure if your AliPay account is a business one, because only a business account can you use the Alipay Express gateway type.

Regarding examples, you can check `liuyug/django-alipay`, which is pretty similar to `spookylukey/django-paypal`, assuming you had experience in integration with PayPal.

*OT: Sorry for not providing the direct links to the GitHub repos mentioned above. StackOverflow kept saying that I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.*

Answer (score 1):

Which you use Alipay gateway API?
It appears you have not applied for the relevant interface privillege or incorrect **partner_id** param.

Whatever you use anyone language,they just it's based on common http request.

Alipay provides a sandbox enviroment.But them use a common **partner_id**.

As far as I know none provided Alipay python SDK.